# How to fix bundle install after switching to zsh?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jekyll

I recently switched from hdd to ssd so i had to reinstall everything from scratch since i wanted a clean ssd and not a clone of the hdd. I am trying to set my website locally but after switching from bash to zsh (using oh my zsh), I am getting the following errors when trying to `bundle install` (see picture). I have tried everything i found on the internet but nothing seems to fix the errors that pop when trying to manually installing `eventmachine` and `http_parser`.

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEI32.png

Do i have to switch back to bash and reinstall everything? (a.i ruby, yarn etc.)

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using some Ruby version management (rbenv, rvm, etc)?

Comment: @SebastianPalma No. It was just a simple install with homebrew. Thing is, if i switch back to bash, it works like it should.

Comment: I personally don't know what you can do as I never used the pre-installed Ruby versions that come with the OS. I can just advise you to use something like rbenv (or any other) and manage your Ruby versions and gems with that. Might worth, for future problems like this.

Comment: @SebastianPalma Update : fixed it. Forgot to switch path for ruby gems from bash to zsh. Thanks!

Comment: @Filip Do us others a favor, write up your answer and accept it, so that the solution is to be found as solution (and not as comment) and the question shows up as solved. Thanks.

Comment: @Felix Thank you for the suggestion. I just posted the answer. Will soon mark it as solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix : Deleting path for ruby gems from `.bash_profile` and adding it to `.zshrc`.

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/bin:$PATH"
```